# load .mat file in simulink from python hdf5storage library

Tags: python, matlab, time-series, simulink, hdf5storage

I am trying to load/read some random data in simulink I created using the Python module `hdf5storage`.

I created `.mat` file in Python (simulink supports version 7.3 only) using this code:

```
# get code on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hdf5storage/0.1.3
import hdf5storage
import numpy as np

matcontent = {}
matcontent[u'some_numbers'] = np.array([10, 50, 20]) # each key must be a   unicode string

hdf5storage.write(matcontent, '.', 'data.mat', matlab_compatible=True)
```

I can load the written file in matlab but not in simulink giving the error:

> Caused by:
>
> Simulink does not support loading the input data in the variable 'bar'
>   in file 'C:......\6D\data.mat'. The From File block can only load
>   MATLAB    timeseries objects, structures of MATLAB timeseries objects,
>   or two-dimensional arrays consisting of one-dimensional, double,
>   non-complex samples.

It says I have to create timeseries objects but how to create it in python?

Comment: I think your array has size `[10, 50, 20]`. Would it work to reshape it to e.g. `[10, 1000]` before saving, and then reshaping back to desired size in Simulink?

Comment: *"[...] or two-dimensional arrays consisting of one-dimensional, double, non-complex samples."*  Does it work with, say, `matcontent[u'some_numbers'] = np.array([[10.0, 50.0, 20.0]])`?

Comment: @mikkola   same result ,no change

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser ...nothing happen